# Unable to debug react-native app using debugger-ui

Tags: android, react-native, debugging

May be this query is solved long back but I'm unable to find the solution

Trying to debug react-native app with the help of http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/. For this i've deployed the app in android emulator, clicked `ctrl + m` | chose `Debug` option but ended up with below error

```
Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome, Consider providing alternative methods to expose this method in debug mode, e.g. by exposing constants ahead-of-time, Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

[image]

To solve this, i gone through [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50864129/3142611), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450549/3142611), [link3](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/issues/776), [link4](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28844#issuecomment-658926564) but unable to solve. Can anyone help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** Follow this only for debugging (which is not depended on DeviceInfo)

After looking into [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/issues/776#issuecomment-533410011), searched whole project for `react-native-device-info` imports and found in two places and initialised like this

```
const uniqueId = DeviceInfo.getUniqueIdSync();
const appVersion = DeviceInfo.getVersionSync();
```

Commented these two lines and assigned some dummy values like

```
const uniqueId = `device`;
const appVersion = `device`;
```

then able to debug the app